# Why isn't my discriminating field being added to my encoded case object using circe?

Tags: json, scala, circe

I have the following code, which I expect to print the type of object being encoded, but it only prints an empty object:

```
import cats.syntax.functor._
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.generic.extras.Configuration
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder}

object Main extends App {

  implicit val customConfig: Configuration = 
    Configuration.default.withDefaults.withDiscriminator("type")

  sealed trait Foo

  final case object Bar extends Foo
  final case object Boo extends Foo

  implicit val encodeEvent: Encoder[Foo] = Encoder.instance {
    case Bar => Bar.asJson
    case Boo => Boo.asJson
  }

  implicit val decodeEvent: Decoder[Foo] =
    List[Decoder[Foo]](
      Decoder[Bar.type].widen,
      Decoder[Boo.type].widen,
    ).reduceLeft(_ or _)

   val bar = Bar

   println((bar: Foo).asJson.noSpaces) // {}
}
```

Why isn't the `Configuration` being applied to the encoding of my `Foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following does work:

```
import cats.syntax.functor._
import io.circe.generic.extras.semiauto._
import io.circe.generic.extras.Configuration
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder}

object Main extends App {

  implicit val customConfig: Configuration =
    Configuration.default.withDefaults.withDiscriminator("type")

  sealed trait Foo

  final case object Bar extends Foo
  final case object Boo extends Foo

  implicit val eBar: Encoder[Bar.type] = deriveEncoder[Bar.type]
  implicit val eBoo: Encoder[Boo.type] = deriveEncoder[Boo.type]


  implicit val dBar: Decoder[Bar.type] = deriveDecoder[Bar.type]
  implicit val dBoo: Decoder[Boo.type] = deriveDecoder[Boo.type]

  implicit val encodeEvent: Encoder[Foo] = deriveEncoder[Foo]

  implicit val decodeEvent: Decoder[Foo] =
    List[Decoder[Foo]](
      Decoder[Bar.type].widen,
      Decoder[Boo.type].widen,
    ).reduceLeft(_ or _)

  val foo: Foo = Boo: Foo

  println(foo.asJson.noSpaces) // {"type":"Boo"}
}
```

---

The things to note are:

1. `Configuration` is (to the best of my knowledge) for `io.circe.generic.extras.semiauto` and not for `io.circe.generic.auto`
2. You had supplied an `Encoder` and did not let it (semi) auto derive. While the configuration is for the (semi) auto derivation.